# How can I find the position of the selected points in the chartJs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to find the position and dataset of the selected points

[image]

I want to do this in tooltip:

```
tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem) {
                //position of dataset & point
        }
    }
}
```

I used the following codes:

```
options: {
            onHover: function(e) {
         var thisLineChart = this.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];

        
         indexPoint = thisLineChart._index;
         datasetIndex = thisLineChart._datasetIndex;

      },
```

}

but i get the following error in the console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_index')

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=chartjs+getPixelForValue+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [other relevant search](https://www.google.com/search?q=chartjs+getElementAtEvent+coordinates+site:stackoverflow.com)